# javascript encodeURIComponent and converting spaces to + symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, encodeuricomponent

I would like to encode my URL, but I want to convert spaces to plus symbols.

This is what I attempted to do...

```
var search = "Testing this here &";

encodeURIComponent(search.replace(/ /gi,"+"));
```

The output from that is `Testing%2Bthis%2Bhere%2B%26` but what I would like it to be is `Testing+this+here+%26` I tried replacing the space with `%20` to convert it into a plus symbol, but that didn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me what it is I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
encodeURIComponent(search).replace(/%20/g, "+");
```

What you're doing wrong here is that *first* you convert spaces to pluses, but then `encodeURIComponent` converts pluses to `"%2B"`.

Comment: That will cause problems if the string contains any "real" `+` characters.

Comment: @user1419007 No it won't. All "original" pluses are converted to `"%2B"` and kept by `replace`.

Comment: Ah, silly me, thank you. I'll select you for best answer when the 8 minutes are up.

Comment: @user1419007 I put %2B instead of %20 at first. Corrected right away.

Comment: This could break multi-byte character encodings.

Comment: I think this could work too? `search.split(' ').map(encodeURIComponent).join('+')`

Answer (score 1):

Just try `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` yourself...

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('@#$%^&*'));
```

Input: `@#$%^&*`.  Output: `%40%23%24%25%5E%26*`.  So, wait, what happened to `*`?  Why wasn't this converted?  TLDR: You actually want [`fixedEncodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [`fixedEncodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).  Long-story...

***Don't use `encodeURIComponent()` directly.***

You should use [`fixedEncodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), as indicated by the MDN Documentation.  `encodeURIComponent` ***does not encode*** any of the following: `!',()*`.  You need to use this other function.  It will solve not only your space problems, but other character problems.

`function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) { return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) { return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); }); }`

To quote the MDN Documentation ***`encodeURIComponent()`***...

> To be more stringent in adhering to RFC 3986 (which reserves !, ', (, ), and *), even though these characters have no formalized URI delimiting uses, the following can be safely used: `fixedEncodeURIComponent()`.