# How do I keep + sign as is in encodeURIComponent("+")?

Tags: javascript

In a part of the code I can't change. The function `encodeURIComponent()` will be executed on the URL i pass in, how ever one of my API calls contains a + sign which is necessary to send as a + sign. Right now it gets replaces "%2B" which makes the API fail..

I have tried using escape and "%2B" and backslash infront of my + sign as "+" but nothing gives so far..

**How do I make encodeURIComponent('+') return + and not "%2B"**

Thank you affordtime for your help

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily swap out the plus signs for an arbitrary marker, e.g.

```
encodeURIComponent("one £ + £ two".replace(/\+/g, '*PLUS*')).replace('*PLUS*', '+');
```

Gives you:

```
"one%20%C2%A3%20+%20%C2%A3%20two"
```

...ie retains the +, which will also survive the reverse trip via `decodeURIComponent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without changing the code. `encodeURIComponent` will never output a `+` sign.

If you or someone else can change the code you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857601/772035):

```
encodeURIComponent(search).replace(/%20/g, "+");
```

and then use spaces in the input where you want `+` to be.

Answer (score 0):

It is not usually recommended to overwrite native functions but you could do this which would redefined encodeURIComponent to not escape plus characters but otherwise escape the same set of characters.

```
function encodeURIComponent(s) {
    // encodeURI leaves these chars untouched @#$&=:/,;?+
    return encodeURI(s).replace(/[@#$&=:\/,;?]/g, function(c) {
        return '%'+c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can't change the behavior of `encodeURIComponent`, the simplest way is to replace `%2B`-s back to `+`-es:

```
encodeURIComponent('1+2=3').replace(/%2B/g, '+') //1+2%3D3
```

This is more efficient, as it needs a single replacement, and doesn't need intermediate "escaping", and simpler, as you don't have to reimplement `encodeURIComponent` and using the native one *might* be even faster for large strings.